# Python: Add new dictionary key that consist of word from previous key

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, key-value

So I build a glossary application using python dictionary. But I found an interesting case which I don't know how to solve it.

For example, I have a dictionary as follows.

```
glos = {'Hypertext Markup Language': 'the standard markup language for documents.',  
        'HTML': 'the standard markup language for documents.',  
        'Semantic Hypertext Markup Language': 'HTML that emphasizes the meaning of the encoded information.'}
```

As you can see, the `Hypertext Markup Language` has the same value as `HTML`, but is there any way to add `Semantic HTML` key with the same value as `Semantic Hypertext Markup Language`?

The end product would be like this:

```
glos = {'Hypertext Markup Language': 'the standard markup language for documents.',  
        'HTML': 'the standard markup language for documents.',  
        'Semantic Hypertext Markup Language': 'HTML that emphasizes the meaning of the encoded information.'
        'Semantic HTML': 'HTML that emphasizes the meaning of the encoded information.'}
```

I thought of creating new dict for key with its abbreviation like this

```
same_val = {'Hypertext Markup Language': 'HTML'}
```

After that, it's gonna loop the key in `glos` dict to find if it has the word from `same_val` dict by using some regex or anything, but I don't know how to properly type it in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a very fragile method. It won't work with variations such as plurals etc. I would suggest against bloating the main glossary but having a separate `aliases` dictionary and use `glos` and `aliases` together when looking up terms. For example:

```
glos = {'Hypertext Markup Language': 'the standard markup language for documents.', 
        'Semantic Hypertext Markup Language': 'HTML that emphasizes the meaning of the encoded information.'}
aliases = {'HTML': 'Hypertext Markup Language',
           'Semantic HTML': 'Semantic Hypertext Markup Language'}
  
def lookup(term):
    return glos.get(term, glos.get(aliases.get(term)))
```

Comment: This is probably the better way to go about doing that, and if 1 key has multiple aliases, the OP can use a list as the value in the `aliases` object.

Answer (score 1):

You want to insert a new key `'Semantic HTML'` into `glos` with the same value as for the key `'Semantic Hypertext Markup Language'`. If my understanding is correct, the code that should accomplish your needs is as follows. Add this after you've created the `glos` object.

```py
glos['Semantic HTML'] = glos['Semantic Hypertext Markup Language']
```

What does this do? We get the value corresponding to the key `'Semantic Hypertext Markup Language'` from the dictionary, and assign that same value back to the dictionary, under the key `'Semantic HTML'`.

Comment: Why use `dict.get()`? It's more pythonic to simply use index notation: `glos['Semantic HTML'] = glos['Semantic Hypertext Markup Language']`

Comment: Very true. I'll edit my answer to update that - feel free to add edits yourself if there's things you think can be improved. I guess it's also good not to mix and match dictionary access methods if there's no need to do so - a bad habit of mine!